# Pipe first X lines to one command, rest to another command

Tags: bash, pipe

Is there an elegant way to split (by lines) the STDOUT of a command to two different programs?

The use case is I have a command that prints out columnar data that I'd like to pipe to `column -t`, but it also prints out some general info and logs at the top, e.g.

```
$ first-command
Connecting to XYZ
Total lines: 2
Id  Status  Type
id-001  INPROGRESS  5
id-002  PENDING 1
```

If I pipe this to `column` as is, I get:

```
$ first-command | column -t
Connecting  to          XYZ
Total       lines:      2
Id          Status      Type
id-001      INPROGRESS  5
id-002      PENDING     1
```

Instead, I'd like it to print the first two lines normally, and then `column` the rest, e.g.

```
$ first-command | split-stdout -n 2 "cat" "column -t"
Connecting to XYZ
Total lines: 2
Id      Status      Type
id-001  INPROGRESS  5
id-002  PENDING     1
```

EDIT: Piping the first X lines straight to STDOUT is fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` works.

I don't have a command spitting out that output, so I just put it into a sample file:

```
$ cat column.txt
Connecting to XYZ
Total lines: 2
Id  Status  Type
id-001  INPROGRESS  5
id-002  PENDING 1
```

Piping this to the following `awk` then gets the output you want:

```
$ cat column.txt | awk 'NR<=2{print;next}{print | "column -t"}'
Connecting to XYZ
Total lines: 2
Id      Status      Type
id-001  INPROGRESS  5
id-002  PENDING     1
```

The code specifically says for line numbers <=2:
 `NR<=2` just print the output and go to the next line:
`{print; next}`.

The next block executes for all lines greater than the second, and prints to a pipe to `column -t`

Comment: Ah, that worked! Sounds like I should learn some more `awk`. Thank you very much!

Comment: RE: deleted comment: Nvm, I committed an off-by-one crime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tee command to "feed" two different commands with the same input:

```
echo "hello world" | tee >(cut -d' ' -f2) | cut -d' ' -f1
```

outputs

```
hello
world
```

For the job you are trying to do you could send the output of the `first-command` to `tee` then print the first 2 lines to an output file `>(head -2 > output)` and print the rest of the lines to process them into the same output `tail -n +3 | column -t >> output`

Comment: For some reason, when I do `first-command | tee >(cut -d' ' -f1) | cut -d' ' -f3`, it works properly (pipe outputs third column, subshell outputs first column), but when I try doing `first-command | tee >(cut -d' ' -f1,2) | cut -d' ' -f3`, the second `cut` is now being applied to the result of the subshell as well... The pipe outputs the third column, subshell outputs empty lines.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant doing this for your specific case `first-command | tee >(head -2 > output) | tail -n +3 | column -t >> output` if you `cat` the output file it should be what you want. Edited the answer to make it more clear

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! That `tee >(subcommand)` syntax is useful. I'll have to keep that in mind.